# Big-O for 2 dimensional array and Linked list

Tags: c++, c, arrays, linked-list, big-o

I've made a game by using 9 linked Lists and the other 1 linked lists gets all the address of the other 9 linked lists. Therefore, something like a 2 dimensional array by using linked list.

I'm trying to calculate Big-O that my data structure fits and is better than the 2 dimensional array but I'm concerned about three things.

1. 2 dimensional array called a[10][10] exists, when I insert a[5][5]=1 is it O(1)?
2. A linked list exists with N nodes, then in order to find the final node is it O(N)?
3. As I said before, I've made a linked list which looks like a 
      2 dimensional array and each linked list has N nodes. 
      If i find each linked list's final node and moves it to each head. Is it O(N^2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2 dimensional array called a[10][10] exists, when I insert a[5][5]=1 is it O(1)?

Nope, it is *O(row index + column index)*, because you need to find one linked list by traversal, then the node in it by another traversal.

> A linked list exists with N nodes, then in order to find the final node is it O(N)?

It depends on the implementation. Some have a special link to the final node, and then it is *O(1)*. A singly-linked list is indeed *O(n)*.

> As I said before, I've made a linked list which looks like a 2 dimensional array and each linked list has N nodes. If i find each linked list's final node and moves it to each head. Is it O(N^2)?

It depends on the previous point: either *O(n)* or *O(n^2)*.

Comment: If the first question is not a linked list and a 2 dimensional array is it also, O(row index + column index)?

Comment: No. If it is a true array of arrays, then it is *O(1)*.

Answer (score -1):

You're right about the first one.
You're also right about the second one.
Now, about third one. You have 9 linked lists. Accessing a final node of a linked list is O(n). So, accessing a final node of every one of 9 linked lists you have would still be O(n), since you have a constant number of linked lists.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is wrong. In the OP's "array", the first is not *O(1)*.

Comment: Then if i have N linked lists and the other linked lists collects the other N linked list . If find the final node and move it to each head, is this O(N^2)?

Comment: @Bartic I might have been wrong about the OP's question. If you edit your question in any way, I'll be able to remove the downvote.

Comment: @AmiTavory I don't know, maybe I am wrong.
If some code has a complexity of O(c), where c is some constant, is that the same as O(1)? I think he meant the true two-dimensional array, not the linked list.

Comment: @양수현 Yes, I believe that would be the case.